# R ggplot2 alluvial plot with simple data

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I'm very new to making graphs in R and I'm having a hard time producing a simple alluvial plot.

My data is basically something like this (I've already aggregated it):

```
data<-tibble(working_2019=c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"),
            working_2022=c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"),
            obs=c(20,30,40,10))
```

This is what I have so far, and when I try following other people's code it never works (mostly because all other examples use the option "fill" to get categories within a stratum, and I don't think it's needed here).

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=obs, axis1=working_2019, axis2=working_2022))+
  geom_alluvium( width=0,knot.pos=0, reverse=F)+
  geom_stratum(width = 1/16)
```

I'd like to get something like this, with 2019 as the left axis and 2022 as the right one, and then label each axis with "Working" and "Not Working"
[image: Example alluvial plot]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the labels on x-axis you could use `scale_x_discrete` with `limits` like this:

```r
library(ggalluvial)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ggplot(data, aes(y=obs, axis1=working_2019, axis2=working_2022))+
  geom_alluvium( width=0,knot.pos=0, reverse=F)+
  geom_stratum(width = 1/16) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("2019", "2022"), expand = c(.05, .05)) 
#> Warning in to_lodes_form(data = data, axes = axis_ind, discern =
#> params$discern): Some strata appear at multiple axes.

#> Warning in to_lodes_form(data = data, axes = axis_ind, discern =
#> params$discern): Some strata appear at multiple axes.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>